# Convert Binary value in .bil file to actual value

Tags: c#, gdal

I try using [Gdal](http://www.gdal.org/) library to read a .bil file. With ReadRaster method (C#), I got pixel value like: 3267231744, 3267756310, 3267478159...How can i convert these value to actual value?
I need do some calculation (+ , -) with pixel value. It's possible to calculate pixel values, then convert final result value ?

```
**.Hdr file:**  
Ulxmap 776310.000000  
ulymap 1821970.000000  
xdim 20.000000  
ydim 20.000000  
ncols 10  
nrows 23  
nbits 32  
nbands 1  
byteorder I  
layout bil  
bandrowbytes 40  
totalrowbytes 40  
skipbytes 0  
datatype R32
```